# Error: unresolvable property or identifier: Base64

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I'm trying to call a REST service that is protected by basic authentication and I can't get this work. Basically, I need to setup the authorization header as 
"Authorization: Basic [base64 encoded user name and password]".

My flow looks like this:

```
<flow name="testjsonFlow1" doc:name="testjsonFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="testjson" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-property propertyName="Authorization"  doc:name="Set Authentication Header" value="#["Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String("username:password")]"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="<url>" port="80" path="Services/V1/testservices" method="POST"   contentType="text/plain" doc:name="HTTP"/>

    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

Invoking this flow results in the following error:

1. [Error: unresolvable property or identifier: Base64] 
   [Near : {... "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String("com ....}]

I see that the MuleStudio ships with commons-codec-1.3-osgi.jar while the Base64 API is not included and only comes with later version.

So my questions are:

1. Is this the right way to call a REST service that is protected with basic auth?
2. How can I resolve this issue?
3. How can I make the Mulestudio reference the commons-codec-1.9 jar instead of the commons-codec-1.3-osgi.jar?

Environment details: Windows 7 64 bit, Mule CE 3.4.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1:**
I made some updates to the script and it works now. Here is the updated script:

```
<flow name="testjsonFlow1" doc:name="testjsonFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="testjson" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <set-variable variableName="uName" doc:name="Variable" value="domain\user"/>
    <set-variable variableName="pwd" doc:name="Variable" value="P@ssword"/>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
      <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
            <scripting:text><![CDATA[
                def cred = message.getInvocationProperty("uName") + ":" + message.getInvocationProperty("pwd")
                def credBytes = cred.bytes
                def encodedCred = credBytes.encodeBase64().toString()
               message.setProperty("credential",encodedCred)
               return null;]]></scripting:text>
      </scripting:script>
  </scripting:component>
    <set-property propertyName="Authorization"  doc:name="Set Authentication Header" value="Basic #[header:OUTBOUND:credential]"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="#[message.outboundProperties['Authorization']]"  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="myserver.com" port="80" path="Services/V1/service1/" method="POST"   contentType="text/plain" doc:name="HTTP" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding user name and password on the http:outbound-endpoint didn't work as the password had a special character ('@') which was throwing a different exception. I made it work with a different approach and updated it in the question.

Comment: Davids suggestion of including the credentials in the URL to work. However if the password contains a '@' you need to URL encode it. So use '%40' instead of '@' in the password when you define it in the URL.

Comment: Thanks Pontus - I'll certainly try it today.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question to david in the comments above but hate pasting code into the comment editor.

You can add the user and pw to the endpoint and it'll base64 encode it like above.

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
    host="foo.bar.com" port="80"
path="getFoo" method="GET"
user="username" password="password">
</http:outbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work for a different reason. The password had '@' character, which was causing the issue. Anyways, I was able to make it work with a different approach, but not sure if that is the best approach. I have updated the code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
  <expression-language>
    <import class="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64" />
  </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

or use the fully qualified class name in your expression.

But...

1. No, configure the username and password on the endpoint. See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Endpoint+URIs
2. Ditto.
3. Don't. Stick to the version provided by Mule. If you insist on using a most recent version, you'll need to package it with your application and use classloader override to ensure your application will use the packaged Commons Codec. See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Classloader+Control+in+Mule#ClassloaderControlinMule-Fine-GrainedClassloadingControl

Comment: David-Thanks for your reply.Couple of issues: 1. I added the <configuration> element before the <flow> element, but I got a different error: Error: unable to resolve method: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(java.lang.String). 2. The REST service expects in the following format:                                                               POST http://myserver/services/ HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver
Authorization: Basic Y494G35tcGFuh3cQWRtaW5Db21wYW55QTpBZG1pbkFAMTIz
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0

Comment: (continued...) I guess to including the credentials in the URL as mentioned in the article will not work. I'm new to mule - can you provide me a working example of setting authorization header?